# Comparing unsigned char with integer literal

Tags: c, casting, char

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char voto;

    printf("Inserire il voto (da 2 a 10): ");
    scanf("%d", &voto);

    printf("\n\n\n%d ", voto);

    if(voto > 1 && voto < 11)
    {
        printf("corrisponde al giudizio ", voto);

        switch(voto)
        {
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                printf("INSUFFICIENTE");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("SUFFICIENTE");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("DISCRETO");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("BUONO");
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("MOLTO BUONO");
                break;
            case 10:
                printf("OTTIMO");
                break;
        }
    } else
    {
        printf("non e' un voto valido!");
    }

    printf("\n\n----------------------------");


    return 0;
}
```

I'll copy the the message my teacher sent me:

> When the IF compares the CHAR and the numeric constant, two things can happen: either the numeric constant gets converted into an UNSIGNED CHAR and gets compared with "voto" alphabetically, or "voto" gets converted into an INT and it gets compared with the literal numerically. In both cases you force the processor to perform  casting and, in the first case, the program may not work correctly:
>   Alphabetically, this would be a correct order:
>   1
>   11
>   111
>   2
>   222
>   23
>   Here 2 results bigger than 11 and 111, and 23 results bigger than 222.

Doesn't this comparison always cause VOTO to be casted into INT, and not the other way? And, if the literal gets cnverted to UNISGNED CHAR, wouldn't the program work the same way?

Comment: I didn't understand a word of what your teacher wrote, nor what you wrote, but `voto`  is an `unsigned char` and the `%d` format specifier with `scanf` requires an `int`. Your compiler should have warned you. Just replace `unsigned char voto;` with `int voto;` and it should work.

Comment: (a) Was your teacher commenting on **only** the version of the code shown in the question, exactly? (b) In C, a literal constant `1` or `11` has type `int` and is not converted to an `unsigned char` in a comparison, regardless of the type of the other operand.

Comment: Yes. And i used %d so I could store a integer from the input to the voto variable

Comment: Is this code your teacher gave you with an associated comment, or is this code you submitted and the teacher's comment on what you wrote?

Comment: the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's exactly the program you submitted, your teacher isn't reading your code very well. There is quite a different problem.

Had you written `scanf("%c", &voto);` then your teacher's comments would make a certain amount of sense, although they seem to be implying that C might cast the character '1' into the value 1, which is certainly not the case. If you really only expected a single character, you could get away with that, although you'd have to change all the other values you compare `voto` with to character literals, since the value of the character `'1'`, for example, is 49. Anyway, that's not going to work because you clearly require the ability to read the number 10, which is two characters long.

But you are correct that the `unsigned char` will be converted to an `int`.

In your actual program, or at least the one pasted here, you've actually written

```
scanf("%d", &voto);
```

and that is certainly *not* correct. The `%d` conversion specifier must have an a pointer to an `int` as its corresponding argument; since it does not, it's Undefined Behaviour. In practice, it's likely that `scanf` will treat the given pointer as being a pointer to a non-existent `int`, and that means that local variables which happen to be in the vicinity of `voto` will be overwritten. (Worse things could happen; that's just to give you an idea.)

Comment: _"local variables which happen to be in the vicinity of voto will be overwritten"_: this may happen, but actually it's just undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Fair enough. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the call of scanf is incorrect because there is used incorrect conversion specifier %d with an object of the type unsigned char.

```
unsigned char voto;
//...
scanf("%d", &voto);
```

Even if you will cast an integer constant to the type unsigned char the usual arithmetic conversions will be applied to the both operands of a relational operation or of the comparison. It means that in the case when the integer constant has the type int or after casting the integer constant to the type unsigned char the both operands will be converted to the type int due to the integer promotions (that is a part of the usual arithmetic conversions) and the integer values of the operands will be compared.This has nothing common with the alphabetical comparison because the integer constant can have any value and it is evident that for example the ASCII value of the character 'A' equal to 65 is less than the integer constant 111.